# How to change default Accounting Number Format?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, default-settings, accounting, currency-format

In most cases, the default accounting format in Excel is **$**

[image: Default account format]

> - Without using some kind of [macro](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/create-a-macro.html)
> - Without changing [timezone](http://www.worldtimezone.com/) (or other system settings) of the computer

How to change this and set another currency as default using Excel's built-in settings?

Comment: Don't use *Accounting* format............instead define a unique ***Style*** to match your needs.

Comment: did you try changing the regional language setting ?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent how unique ***Style*** is set in excel? P.Obertelli - I'm trying to avoid system level changes.

Answer (score 2):

To create a new **Style** just click on *Cell Styles* in the *Home* tab and then click on *New cell style...*

[image]

Comment: just a confusion - does it changes the default currency format for Excel?

Comment: @student You can apply the **Style** to a cell from the *Styles* menu

Comment: I m not sure whether ***Style*** will solve my problem or not however this will be "new" learning for me. Thanks!